# How to yield multiple list objects by appending values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, generator, boto3

I have the following code that fetches resources information from AWS service called `resourcegroupstaggingapi` from all AWS supported regions. Right now I am iterating through multiple regions and fetching the records successfully but my problem is that it takes a lot of time to process and `CPU memory` is also used a lot and execution time is very high, I've around `40 million records` to process. Can someone tell me what is the best way to optimize this code? I see that generators improve ***performance*** and ***execution speed*** but I'm not sure how to `append` and `yield` multiple values. I'm new to Python as well, can someone guide me on how to improve the following code:

```
import boto3, os, json
from credentials import AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

AWS_SUPPORTED_REGIONS = ["ap-northeast-1", "ap-northeast-2", "ap-south-1", "ap-southeast-1", "ap-southeast-2",
                         "ca-central-1", "eu-central-1", "eu-north-1", "eu-west-1", "eu-west-2", "eu-west-3",
                         "sa-east-1", "us-east-1", "us-east-2", "us-west-1", "us-west-2"]


def services_info():
    services_info = []
    services_info_no_owner = []
    for region in AWS_SUPPORTED_REGIONS:
        client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi', region_name=region,
                              aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                              aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                              )
        paginator = client.get_paginator('get_resources')
        resources = []
        for page in paginator.paginate():
            resources.extend(page["ResourceTagMappingList"])
        for resource in resources:
            resource_arn = resource.get("ResourceARN")
            arn_split = resource_arn.split(':')
            service_name = arn_split[2]
            resource_owner_info = arn_split[3]
            services_info.append({
                "resource_arn": resource_arn,
                "service_name": service_name,
                "region": region,
                "owner_info": resource_owner_info
            })
            if services_info_no_owner.isspace():
                services_info_no_owner.append({
                    "resource_arn": resource_arn,
                    "service_name": service_name,
                    "region": region,
                    "owner_info": resource_owner_info
                })
    return services_info, services_info_no_owner


services_info, services_info_no_owner = services_info()

try:
    with open("services_info.json", 'w') as output:
        json.dump(services_info, output, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception occurred while writing to file")

try:
    with open("services_info_no_owner.json", 'w') as output:
        json.dump(services_info_no_owner, output, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception occurred while writing to file")
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I removed lines where you kept defining new variables by applying something to new to it, and instead put them all on one line, this would free up memory.
2. I tried to convert were possible your code into generators, since they are more optimized

```
import boto3, os, json
from credentials import AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

AWS_SUPPORTED_REGIONS = ["ap-northeast-1", "ap-northeast-2", "ap-south-1", "ap-southeast-1", "ap-southeast-2",
                         "ca-central-1", "eu-central-1", "eu-north-1", "eu-west-1", "eu-west-2", "eu-west-3",
                         "sa-east-1", "us-east-1", "us-east-2", "us-west-1", "us-west-2"]

def services_info():
    services_info = []
    services_info_no_owner = []

    def go(region):
        resources = [page["ResourceTagMappingList"] for page in boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi', region_name=region,
                              aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                              aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                              ).get_paginator('get_resources').paginate()]

        [(services_info.append({
                "resource_arn": resource.get("ResourceARN").split(':'),
                "service_name": resource.get("ResourceARN").split(':')[2],
                "region": region,
                "owner_info":  resource.get("ResourceARN").split(':')[3]
            }), services_info_no_owner.append({
                    "resource_arn": resource.get("ResourceARN"),
                    "service_name": resource.get("ResourceARN").split(':')[2],
                    "region": region,
                    "owner_info": resource.get("ResourceARN").split(':')[3]
                }))

         if services_info_no_owner.isspace()

         else services_info.append({
                "resource_arn": resource.get("ResourceARN").split(':'),
                "service_name": resource.get("ResourceARN").split(':')[2],
                "region": region,
                "owner_info":  resource.get("ResourceARN").split(':')[3]
            })  for resource in resources]

    list(map(lambda region: go(region),AWS_SUPPORTED_REGIONS))

    return services_info, services_info_no_owner


services_info, services_info_no_owner = services_info()

try:
    with open("services_info.json", 'w') as output:
        json.dump(services_info, output, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception occurred while writing to file")

try:
    with open("services_info_no_owner.json", 'w') as output:
        json.dump(services_info_no_owner, output, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception occurred while writing to file")
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, let me check and update the answer

Comment: no problem, I guess could cut a few more variables.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the code does not seem to be the right code since
isspace() function will fail on the list services_info_no_owner as
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isspace'

One of the major reason your code is slow you are creating
dictionary items which is very slow compared to say list/tuple

40 million times you are writing the (column)headings in the file.
"resource_arn"
"service_name"
"region"
"owner_info"
Imagine time and space being used for writing
40 miliion * roughly 40 bytes = 1600 million bytes
So json is not the right format. One suggestion is to use pandas
dataframe and then use to_csv() to write to csv file or
simply use lists and write to csv manually.
The major benefit is you will not have to append dictionary to list

With the existing code you can use list comprehension repalcing the first for loop

```
for page in paginator.paginate():
    resources.extend(page["ResourceTagMappingList"])
```

with

```
resources.extend([page["ResourceTagMappingList"] for page in paginator.paginate()])
```

Replace second for loop as follows. Make up for the lost readability using comments.
service_name and resource_owner_info are already in your resource_arn then there is no
need to store them separately. Also region will be in resource_arn as well so need to
store that as well.

```
for resource in resources:
    resource_arn = resource.get("ResourceARN")
    arn_split = resource_arn.split(':')
    service_name = arn_split[2]
    resource_owner_info = arn_split[3]
    services_info.append({"resource_arn": resource_arn,"service_name": service_name,"region": region,"owner_info": resource_owner_info})
```

with

```
services_info = [resource.get("ResourceARN") for resource in resources]
```

I know that both above suggestions will require negotiating skills with the
users of of your json file but when you have 40 million records the significant
improvement achieved is worth the effort.